# Why performance is reduced much when I run a for loop with a count of 5368709120 and few lines of memcpy?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, memory, memcpy

I am allocating three large sized byte arrays and initialized them to some values. I have to perform operations on every 64 bits between these three arrays. I have created a for loop to loop through these arrays and convert consecutive 8 byte(64bit) into 64 bit integer using memcpy and perform operations between them. Later, have calculated the time taken by for loop. I have given my code here.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
BYTE* buffer1;
BYTE* buffer2;
BYTE* buffer3;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long offsetValue = 0;
    int64_t data1, data2, data3;
    unsigned long long BufferSize = 5368709120;
    buffer1 = (BYTE*)malloc(BufferSize);
    buffer2 = (BYTE*)malloc(BufferSize);
    buffer3 = (BYTE*)malloc(BufferSize);
    memset(buffer1, 0, BufferSize);
    memset(buffer2, 1, BufferSize);
    memset(buffer3, 1, BufferSize);
    bool overallResult = false;
    bool stopOnFail = false;
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (unsigned long long i = 0, cycle = 0; i<BufferSize; i += 8, ++cycle)
    {
        long long offset = (offsetValue * 8) + i;
        if (offset> BufferSize - 1)
            break;
        else if (offset< 0)
            continue;
        memcpy(&data1, buffer1 + offset, sizeof(int64_t));
        if (data1 == -1)
            continue;
        memcpy(&data2, buffer2 + offset, sizeof(int64_t));
        memcpy(&data3, buffer3 + offset, sizeof(int64_t));
        int64_t Exor = data2 ^ data3^-1;
        int64_t Or = Exor | data1;
        bool result = Or == -1;

        overallResult &= result;
        if (!result)
        {
            if (stopOnFail)
                break;
        }
    }
    auto ending = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "For loop Execution time in milliseconds :"
        << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(ending - start).count()
        << " ms" << endl;
    free(buffer1);
    free(buffer2);
    free(buffer3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For loop count of 4294967296 gave me a time of 760 milliseconds. But for loop count of 5368709120 gives me a time of 25000 milliseconds. What is draining the time in for loop? How should I optimize?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not using the value `overallResult` outside the loop, so a good optimizing compiler can optimize away the loop entirely. MSVC is probably isn't that smart, but it's still a good idea to e.g. print out `overallResult` at the end.

2. You're allocating (and actually using) 3 × 5,368,709,120 bytes = 15 GB. A Windows 10 system uses a lot more than 1 GB to run (especially in combination with Visual Studio), so on a system with 16 GB, allocating 15 GB would inevitably cause [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging), which is most probably what you're observing (also, a ~20..40x slowdown is characteristic of memory paging).

To verify:

- Open up *Performance Monitor* (`perfmon.exe`)
- Add *Counters* -> *Paging File* -> *% Usage*
- Run your program

If the paging counters are > 0, then you don't have enough RAM, and looping over memory will slow down due to reading of pages from disk.

You can also watch RAM usage in *Task Manager* -> *Performance* tab.

Comment: Not sure how smart MSVC is, but it certainly doesn't refer to any of the buffers in the loop. The loop itself looks silly in asm, I will admit - it's empty. Also wanted to note that `overallResult &= <anything>` is going to be false, as you start with `bool overallResult = false;` :) But trust me - it is optimized out by MSVC.

Comment: @rustyx Paging counters values are always greater than 0. Paging % usage is around 7. It stays the same even after the completion of first execution. Do I need to reset or something? As you said, RAM Usage is around 15GB for 15GB array size and around 10 GB for 9 GB array size. I think more RAM size is required to improve performance. Thanks.

Comment: @VladFeinstein overallResult is initialized to true and I am using it later in my application.   stopOnFail is also set to be true. I left many logics and I just tried a small portion of code to test the performance alone. memcpy would use all the buffers completely and that takes a hit in performance. Compiler optimizations else where doesn't help performance.